# Angular date picker modal is not appearing as expected

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

I am trying to add angular datepicker in my application but the calender modal is not working as expected. I am explaining my code below.

> admin.component.html:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Custom calender color</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="and placeholder">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker1 color="primary"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

> app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';
import { NgxPopper } from 'angular-popper';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { LandingPageParentComponent } from './components/landing-page-parent/landing-page-parent.component';
import { AuthService } from './service/auth/auth.service';
import { AuthGuardService } from './service/auth/auth-guard.service';
import { JwtHelperService, JWT_OPTIONS } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { ContentViewerModalComponent } from './components/content-viewer-modal/content-viewer-modal.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './components/admin/admin.component';
import {
  MatSliderModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule
} from "@angular/material";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    LandingPageParentComponent,
    ContentViewerModalComponent,
    AdminComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule,
    NgxPopper,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([]),
    MatSliderModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule

  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ContentViewerModalComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AuthGuardService,
    {
      provide: JWT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: JWT_OPTIONS
    },
    JwtHelperService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here I am adding `angular material datepicker` and also it working. But when user is clicking on calender icon it giving the modal like below.

[image]

I need to get the proper calendar modal after clicking on icon. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?